# How to convert hash tables to embedded (nested) hash tables with Ruby?

Tags: json, ruby, hash, md5

I have such hash tables:

```
h={"c4"=>1, "c8"=>2, "ec"=>3, "a"=>4, "e4"=>5, "1"=>6, "8"=>7}
```

I can access value 2 as: `h["c8"]`

I would like to convert the hash table to an embedded hash table like this:

```
h={"c"=>{"4"=>1, "8"=>2}, "e"=>{"c"=>3, "4"=>5}, "a"=>4, "1"=>6, "8"=>7}
```

So I could access value 2 as: `h["c"]["8"]` and all the other values too in a similar manner respectively.

All in all instead of:

```
h["c8"]
```

I would prefer to use:

```
h["c"]["8"]
```

Because I would like to recognize strings in javascript. So I would like to build a very large embedded hash table with Ruby, dump it to JSON and load into javascript. Such embedded hash tables are more easier to look up than the original ones. Keys come from MD5 hashing some original values which were filenames, and then finding minimal slices from the beginning of the MD5 hashed keys which are still uniq.

Another longer example:

```
h={"c4"=>1,
 "c8"=>2,
 "ec"=>3,
 "a8"=>4,
 "e4"=>5,
 "1"=>6,
 "8"=>7,
 "c9"=>8,
 "4"=>9,
 "d"=>10,
 "6"=>11,
 "c2"=>12,
 "c5"=>13,
 "aa"=>14}
```

Would be:

```
h={"c"=>{"4"=>1, "8"=>2, "9"=>8, "2"=>12, "5"=>13},
 "e"=>{"c"=>3, "4"=>5},
 "a"=>{"8"=>4, "a"=>14},
 "1"=>6,
 "8"=>7,
 "4"=>9,
 "d"=>10,
 "6"=>11}
```

Even longer example:

```
 h={"c4"=>1, "c8"=>2, "ec"=>3, "a8"=>4, "e4"=>5, "16"=>6, "8f"=>7, "c9"=>8, "45"=>9, "d3"=>10, "65"=>11, "c2"=>12, "c5"=>13, "aa"=>14, "9b"=>15, "c7"=>16, "7"=>17, "6f"=>18, "1f0"=>19, "98"=>20, "3c"=>21, "b"=>22, "37"=>23, "1ff"=>24, "8e"=>25, "4e"=>26, "0"=>27, "33"=>28, "6e"=>29, "3417"=>30, "c1"=>31, "63"=>32, "18"=>33, "e3"=>34, "1c"=>35, "19"=>36, "a5b"=>37, "a57"=>38, "d67"=>39, "d64"=>40, "3416"=>41, "a1"=>42}
```

Would be:

```
h={"c"=>{"4"=>1, "8"=>2, "9"=>8, "2"=>12, "5"=>13, "7"=>16, "1"=>31},
 "e"=>{"c"=>3, "4"=>5, "3"=>34},
 "a"=>{"8"=>4, "a"=>14, "5"=>{"b"=>37, "7"=>38}, "1"=>42},
 "1"=>{"6"=>6, "f"=>{"0"=>19, "f"=>24}, "8"=>33, "c"=>35, "9"=>36},
 "8"=>{"f"=>7, "e"=>25},
 "4"=>{"5"=>9, "e"=>26},
 "d"=>{"3"=>10, "6"=>{"7"=>39, "4"=>40}},
 "6"=>{"5"=>11, "f"=>18, "e"=>29, "3"=>32},
 "9"=>{"b"=>15, "8"=>20},
 "7"=>17,
 "3"=>{"c"=>21, "7"=>23, "3"=>28, "4"=>{"1"=>{"7"=>30, "6"=>41}}},
 "b"=>22,
 "0"=>27}
```

My attempt to solve this problem is a bit ugly and uses "eval", "h" is the original hash:

```
nested_hash={}
h.keys.each{|k| 
  k.split(//).each_with_index{|b,i| 

     if nested_hash.dig(*k[0..i].split(//))==nil then
      eval("nested_hash"+k[0..i].split(//).map{|z| "[\"#{z}\"]"}.join+"={}")
     end
     if i==k.size-1 then
      eval("nested_hash"+k[0..i].split(//).map{|z| "[\"#{z}\"]"}.join+"=h[k]")
     end
  };
};
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We'd like to see your attempt toward solving the problem. Without that it looks like you gave us requirements and expect us to write the code for you.

Comment: What would be the desired result if `h = { "a"=>1, "aa"=>2 }`? Perhaps `{ "a"=>{""=>1, "a"=>2 }`?

Comment: Those key combination isn't allowed in my case, because the minimalization process I apply on the MD5 transformed keys doesn't emit keys which are prefix of other keys. But in a general case: yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment on the question posted by the OP, I've assumed that there are no keys `k1` and `k2`, `k2.size > k1.size`, for which `k2[0, ki.size] == k1`.

**Code**

```
def splat_hash(h)
  h.select { |k,_| k.size > 1 }.
    group_by { |k,_| k[0] }.
    map { |k0,a| [k0, splat_hash(a.map { |k,v| [k[1..-1],v] }.to_h)] }.
    to_h.
    merge(h.select{ |k,_| k.size == 1 })
end
```

**Examples**

*#1*

```
h = {"c4"=>1, "c8"=>2, "ec"=>3, "a"=>4, "e4"=>5, "1"=>6, "8"=>7}
splat_hash h
  #=> {"c"=>{"4"=>1, "8"=>2}, "e"=>{"c"=>3, "4"=>5}, "a"=>4, "1"=>6, "8"=>7}
```

*#2*

```
h = { "c4"=>1, "c8"=>2, "ec"=>3, "a8"=>4, "e4"=>5, "16"=>6, "8f"=>7, "c9"=>8,
      "45"=>9, "d3"=>10, "65"=>11, "c2"=>12, "c5"=>13, "aa"=>14, "9b"=>15,
      "c7"=>16, "7"=>17, "6f"=>18, "1f0"=>19, "98"=>20, "3c"=>21, "b"=>22,
      "37"=>23, "1ff"=>24, "8e"=>25, "4e"=>26, "0"=>27, "33"=>28, "6e"=>29,
      "3417"=>30, "c1"=>31, "63"=>32, "18"=>33, "e3"=>34, "1c"=>35, "19"=>36,
      "a5b"=>37, "a57"=>38, "d67"=>39, "d64"=>40, "3416"=>41, "a1"=>42 }
splat_hash h
  #=> {"c"=>{"4"=>1, "8"=>2, "9"=>8, "2"=>12, "5"=>13, "7"=>16, "1"=>31},
  #    "e"=>{"c"=>3, "4"=>5, "3"=>34},
  #    "a"=>{"5"=>{"b"=>37, "7"=>38}, "8"=>4, "a"=>14, "1"=>42},
  #    "1"=>{"f"=>{"0"=>19, "f"=>24}, "6"=>6, "8"=>33, "c"=>35, "9"=>36},
  #    "8"=>{"f"=>7, "e"=>25},
  #    "4"=>{"5"=>9, "e"=>26},
  #    "d"=>{"6"=>{"7"=>39, "4"=>40}, "3"=>10},
  #    "6"=>{"5"=>11, "f"=>18, "e"=>29, "3"=>32},
  #    "9"=>{"b"=>15, "8"=>20},
  #    "3"=>{"4"=>{"1"=>{"7"=>30, "6"=>41}}, "c"=>21, "7"=>23, "3"=>28},
  #    "7"=>17,
  #    "b"=>22,
  #    "0"=>27}
```

*#3*

```
h = { "a"=>1, "ba"=>2, "bb"=>3, "caa"=>4, "cab"=>5, "daba"=>6, "dabb"=>7, "dabcde"=>8 }
splat_hash h
  #=> {"b"=>{"a"=>2, "b"=>3},
  #    "c"=>{"a"=>{"a"=>4, "b"=>5}},
  #    "d"=>{"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>{"d"=>{"e"=>8}},"a"=>6, "b"=>7}}},
  #    "a"=>1}
```

**Explanation**

I think the best way to show what's happening is to add some `puts` statements to the code and run it with an example.

```
INDENT_SIZE = 6

def putsi(str)
  puts "#{' ' * @indent}#{str}"
end

def indent
  @indent = (@indent ||= 0) + INDENT_SIZE
end

def undent
  @indent -= INDENT_SIZE
end

def splat_hash(h)
  puts
  indent
  putsi "enter splat_hash with h=#{h}"
  h.select { |k,_| k.size > 1 }.
    tap { |g| putsi "  select > 1 = #{g}" }.
    group_by { |k,_| k[0] }.
    tap { |g| putsi "  group_by = #{g}" }.
    map { |k0,a| putsi "    calling splat_hash";
          [k0, splat_hash(a.map { |k,v| [k[1..-1],v] }.to_h)] }.
    tap { |a| putsi "  map = #{a}" }.        
    to_h.
    tap { |g| putsi "  to_h = #{g}" }.
    merge(h.select{ |k,_| k.size == 1 }).
    tap { |g| putsi "  returning g = #{g}" }.
    tap { undent }        
end
```

```
h = {"c4"=>1, "c8"=>2, "ec"=>3, "faa"=>4, "e4"=>5,  "fab"=>6, "1"=>7 }

splat_hash h
  enter splat_hash with h={"c4"=>1, "c8"=>2, "ec"=>3, "faa"=>4, "e4"=>5,
                           "fab"=>6, "1"=>7}
    select > 1 = {"c4"=>1, "c8"=>2, "ec"=>3, "faa"=>4, "e4"=>5, "fab"=>6}
    group_by = {"c"=>[["c4", 1], ["c8", 2]], "e"=>[["ec", 3], ["e4", 5]],
                "f"=>[["faa", 4], ["fab", 6]]}
      calling splat_hash
```

```
        enter splat_hash with h={"4"=>1, "8"=>2}
          select > 1 = {}
          group_by = {}
          map = []
          to_h = {}
          returning g = {"4"=>1, "8"=>2}
      calling splat_hash
```

```
        enter splat_hash with h={"c"=>3, "4"=>5}
          select > 1 = {}
          group_by = {}
          map = []
          to_h = {}
          returning g = {"c"=>3, "4"=>5}
      calling splat_hash
```

```
        enter splat_hash with h={"aa"=>4, "ab"=>6}
          select > 1 = {"aa"=>4, "ab"=>6}
          group_by = {"a"=>[["aa", 4], ["ab", 6]]}
            calling splat_hash
```

```
              enter splat_hash with h={"a"=>4, "b"=>6}
                select > 1 = {}
                group_by = {}
                map = []
                to_h = {}
                returning g = {"a"=>4, "b"=>6}

          map = [["a", {"a"=>4, "b"=>6}]]
          to_h = {"a"=>{"a"=>4, "b"=>6}}
          returning g = {"a"=>{"a"=>4, "b"=>6}}

    map = [["c", {"4"=>1, "8"=>2}], ["e", {"c"=>3, "4"=>5}],
           ["f", {"a"=>{"a"=>4, "b"=>6}}]]
    to_h = {"c"=>{"4"=>1, "8"=>2}, "e"=>{"c"=>3, "4"=>5}, "f"=>{"a"=>{"a"=>4, "b"=>6}}}
    returning g = {"c"=>{"4"=>1, "8"=>2}, "e"=>{"c"=>3, "4"=>5},
                   "f"=>{"a"=>{"a"=>4, "b"=>6}}, "1"=>7}
#=> {"c"=>{"4"=>1, "8"=>2},
#    "e"=>{"c"=>3, "4"=>5},
#    "f"=>{"a"=>{"a"=>4, "b"=>6}}, "1"=>7}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're describing a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).
I've had good experience with [triez](https://github.com/luikore/triez) and [trie](https://github.com/tyler/trie) gems.

You'd need to iterate over `key,value` pairs in your hash and add the md5 strings to the trie with the value at the leaf.

At the end, you'd export the whole structure to a nested hash or define `to_json` on a trie Node.

PS: Your question is interesting and well asked. You didn't provide any code though, so I won't either ;)

Comment: It is probably worth using a gem here rather than janky home-rolled code.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a combination of `reduce` and `chars`.

```
h={"c4"=>1, "c8"=>2, "ec"=>3, "a"=>4, "e4"=>5, "1"=>6, "8"=>7}
result = h.reduce({}) do |memo, (k,v)|
  key, nested_key = k.to_s.chars
  if nested_key
    memo[key] ||= {}
    memo[key][nested_key] = v
  else
    memo[key] = v
  end
  memo
end
# => {"c"=>{"4"=>1, "8"=>2}, "e"=>{"c"=>3, "4"=>5}, "a"=>4, "1"=>6, "8"=>7}
```

If you want to have keys of more than 1 char, or more levels of nesting, you'd need a little more work, but that hopefully gives you an idea.

Comment: Level of nesting is governed by the keys structure could be 5 or even 10 or more. Limit is 32 as the longest possible key in this scenario is 32 character because it comes from an MD5 hash which is 32 character long.

Answer (score 0):

Ultra simple non-recursive (iterative) solution inspired by JavaScript, variable `to` acts like a pointer in the structure:

```
def nested_hash(h)
  bh={};
  h.keys.each{|k|
        to=bh
        k[0..-2].each_char{|c|
          if to[c]==nil then
            to[c]={}  
          end
          to=to[c]
        }
        to[k[-1]]=h[k]
  } 
  return bh
end
```